# How to get the value of a variable from the collection

Tags: laravel

```
   public function returnsTrueIfEmailIsVerified(Request $request)
    {
        // Gets the email
        $email = request("email"); //johndoe@example.com for example
        // Determine if zero or one ;
        $user  = User::where('email','=',$email)->get(); // 0 or 1  ;

        $userCount  = User::where('email','=',$email)->count(); // 0 or 1  ;

        $confirmedValue = $user->get('confirmed');


        $response ;

        if ( $user === 1 && $confirmedValue === true ) {
            $response = 'OK';
        }
        elseif ($user === 1 && $confirmedValue === false) {
            $response = 'Not Confirmed yet';
        }
        else { 
            $response = 'Not Registered yet';
        }
        return response()->json(200,$response);

    }
```

with that code I would return a response that if a user isn't registered or is registered and that if he's registered but that he's not confirmed yet..

I want to return something out from that I'm not just familiar with laravel's way

Answer (score 1):

There are so many error in your code, I've fixed it and this code will work. I think you need to learn more Laravel and PHP.

```
public function returnsTrueIfEmailIsVerified(Request $request)
{
    $email = request("email");
    $user = User::where('email', '=', $email);

    $response = [
        'message' => ''
    ];

    if ($user->count() === 1) {
        $confirmedValue = $user->first()->confirmed;
        if ($confirmedValue) {
            $response['message'] = 'OK';
        } else {
            $response['message'] = 'Not Confirmed yet';
        }
    } else {
        $response['message'] = 'Not Registered yet';
    }

    return response()->json($response, 200);
}
```

- you can't response string as a json, json is key value pair.
- `User::where('email', '=', $email)` return Query Builder not 0 or 1, use `count()` method;
- you can't retrieve value from multiple items you have to specific item like this `$user->get()[0]['confirmed]` or use Laravel special method `$user->first()->confirmed`

Comment: I tried your code, but didn't got the right answer, The only thing I don't know is the first command, I can use it. I got what I need.

Comment: @TheBAST what do you mean by  *didn't got the right answer*, can you please be more specific, you got error from the code? or got wrong response?